# How to make a VerticalDivider resize to match its SingleChildScrollView parent?

Tags: flutter, layout

I have a `VerticalDivider` inside a `Row` inside `Column` inside a `SingleChildScrollView` inside a `LayoutBuilder`:

```
LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraints) => 
                [...]
                 SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                   [...]
                                    VerticalDivider(
                                            width: 1,
                                            thickness: 1,
                                          ),
                                   [...]
```

The way it is, the `VerticalDivider` is not showing up. I guess it doesn't know its height.

If I put a `SizedBox` around the `VerticalDivider`, with height from `LayoutBuilder` or `MediaQuery`, it will set the height once and when I scroll down, the vertical divider won't reach all the way to the bottom.

How can I make a vertical divider resize with its parent. I get an error message with `double.infinity` since `SingleChildScrollView`doesn't give vertical bounds.

Did I explain this properly?

[image]

Comment: can you assign it a color to make sure it is not visible

Comment: yes, i put it inside a Countainer with a color and the container doesn't reach the bottom

Comment: you got solution?

Comment: No, I updated the question tho.

Comment: did you find any solution? i am just curious:)

Answer (score 0):

I used the `InstrinsicHeight` Widget, wich is cost-intensiv and leads to problem which widget, that can't calculate an intrinsic height, but it works for now.

Answer (score -2):

increase the width and it will became visible you have given 1 width which is too small to notice.

try this:

```
 VerticalDivider(
    width: 20,
    thickness: 1,
   ),
```

checkout the difference between output for width 1 and width 20

> width:1;

[image]

> width:20;

[image]

Comment: no, that's definitely not it

Comment: can you share the screenshot

Comment: checkout the answer for different output using width 1 and width 20

Comment: Doesn't change the fact, that the divider doesn't reach the bottom, see updated question.

Comment: can you include a clear screenshot its hard to identify where you have put the divider and where are the other widgets